# Parse.com+CakePHP+OAuth-2.0, anybody use them together?

Tags: cakephp, rest, oauth-2.0, parse-platform

I've been looking for the best way to build a search web/ios/android application with user login and a REST Webservice. I have landed on CakePHP for the Website creation and REST api handling.

I would also use the RestKit API for iOS, and not sure for what RestAPI I'd use for Android.

I also want to be able to use OAuth-2.0 for communicating with Twitter/Facebook/Pinterest.

**My Question:**
Is there a way to use CakePHP and Parse.com together to handle all the user authentication, and would I need to separate data tables (one on parse.com and the other on another hosting service with CakePHP)?

I would like to keep everything at Parse.com if I could. Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with CakePHP, but if you can completely ignore whatever DB/ORM comes with it by default, you can use Parse on your server and in client apps. There's an [un-official PHP library](https://github.com/apotropaic/parse.com-php-library) you can use for the server, and they offer [iOS and Android SDKs](https://parse.com/docs/api_libraries).